# The type or namespace name 'System' and 'Xamarin' could not be found

Tags: c#, xamarin, namespaces

In visual studio 2017, I created a new Cross-Platform project, Mobile app (Xamarin Forms). I choose Blank project for the Android platform and shared code. NET Standard.

Without entering a new line of code, when solutio was created I get an error that said: "The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found"

[image]

Restore NuGet packages, didn't work.
Clean solution, didn't work.
Buid project, didn't work
...

Has anyone happened to you?

Comment: Have you tried restarting VS?

Comment: Try to rebuild the project and see what you have in the Output. Problems like this do happen, but most of those errors are false, Output should show the real errors. only

Comment: Try to delete bin and obj folders in your .NET standard and Android/iOS project.Then clean solution and build.

Answer (score 1):

I just unloaded the project and then I reloaded on VS 2019, at least for me worked. I hope this could help someone.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case this worked for me:

1. Right click on the project -> **Unload Project**
2. Right click on the project -> **Reload Project with Dependencies**

Answer (score 0):

Just clean your project. You can find it in Build tab.

Answer (score 0):

**The solution was reinstall visual studio and all components. Now, when I create a new project, start with no errors and can compile and execute without any problems.**

Answer (score -1):

Something is wrong with your xamarin installation. I hate to say it but reinstalling xamarin is probably your only option